# How to set HEAD and Middle and BOTTOM image as backgrounds into my webpage?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 photos which i'm willing to make them as head background , middle back ground and finally bottom background , any ideas how would i do that?
Thanks and kindness be with you !

- this photo : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKFF6.jpg - shows that the background i have made finally is scaling to fit the browser , but the top and bottom photos are not scaling as i made another smaller window to show it..
- the current code i have here: `

  ```
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
            background-image: url("TBG_02.jpg");
            background-color: #cccccc;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
         }
      #top,#bottom{width:100%;}
      #top,#bottom{height:200px;}
      #bottom{position: fixed;right:0;bottom:0;}
      .topp{background-image: url("BG_02.png");background-repeat: no-repeat;}
      .bottomm{background-image:url("BG_03.png");background-repeat: no-repeat;position:fixed;}
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  ```

  `
  i would like as well to fix that my image is not sticking to the bottom * it is up a little bit *  .

Comment: Combine the images into one and use that as the background.

Comment: Could you post an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @k1dev edited..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here but I'm guessing you mean you have this code:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

And want each `div` to have a different background image in which case you can do the following; just keep your existing `div` elements in place and just add this css:

```
#header{
background-image: url("yourImage0.jpg");
}

#middle{
background-image: url("yourImage1.jpg");
}

#bottom{
background-image: url("yourImage2.jpg");
}
```

Comment: In that case, you can just use the `position: fixed;` attribute on your header and footer so they stick to the top and bottom of the screen respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
}
.footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:2;
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
}
.body{
  padding:10vh;
  background-color:transparent;
}
.background{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
*{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<img class="header" src="https://stoffe.kawaiifabric.com/images/product_images/large_img/solid-red-fabric-Robert-Kaufman-USA-Red-179485-1.JPG"></img>

<div class="body">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce volutpat leo ut est laoreet sagittis. Nam auctor tellus quis egestas blandit. Praesent posuere hendrerit elementum. Mauris cursus dui leo, sed imperdiet enim ullamcorper at. Fusce congue tempus felis, eget pellentesque erat suscipit eget. Proin non eros tortor. Sed cursus odio eu dolor eleifend, at aliquet justo accumsan.

Nullam sem nisl, lacinia ut efficitur eu, consectetur et justo. Duis efficitur sem et molestie interdum. Sed sodales ut turpis at maximus. Maecenas pellentesque dignissim quam id finibus. Integer leo magna, auctor id iaculis vitae, porttitor vitae nisi. Proin a iaculis sapien. Proin quis faucibus ante, nec ultrices ante. Phasellus placerat metus eu massa convallis, vitae feugiat velit dictum. Cras mattis sed elit eget varius. Sed ultrices tincidunt odio, pellentesque luctus mi laoreet at.

Proin ornare massa leo, et vulputate urna gravida ac. Integer vel augue mauris. Praesent vitae tellus orci. Etiam porttitor libero magna, a euismod mi hendrerit ut. Etiam elementum lectus quis eros iaculis, a iaculis nisl fringilla. Vivamus ultricies porta pellentesque. Sed consequat lorem gravida turpis hendrerit, sit amet vulputate velit cursus. Etiam dignissim ut est nec vulputate.

Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam mi ante, maximus vitae malesuada viverra, pellentesque elementum nulla. Morbi libero ex, ornare sit amet tellus sit amet, lacinia pulvinar risus. Donec porta congue massa quis tincidunt. Suspendisse elit sem, rutrum sed maximus ut, iaculis quis libero. Integer ac vehicula nisi, vitae feugiat turpis. Quisque in ullamcorper mi. Maecenas sed leo luctus, consectetur orci sed, efficitur odio.

Curabitur aliquet, erat eget sodales venenatis, ligula lorem auctor risus, quis sodales sapien ex eget nibh. Etiam a augue neque. Quisque semper eleifend nisl sit amet auctor. Ut sagittis lacus sit amet tempus hendrerit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Suspendisse elementum erat sit amet volutpat rhoncus. Suspendisse vehicula mattis metus sodales volutpat. Aliquam sit amet est sodales, venenatis tortor ac, porta turpis. Sed et eros id felis faucibus egestas. Curabitur mauris sem, posuere ac erat at, cursus varius mi. Vestibulum bibendum ornare ullamcorper. Vivamus sapien ipsum, pharetra quis aliquet et, auctor eget nulla. Pellentesque vel eleifend nisi, in blandit lacus.

Etiam lobortis congue viverra. Quisque fermentum ornare nibh, eget posuere turpis rutrum ac. Maecenas vitae dolor maximus, pretium leo sed, efficitur enim. Sed auctor faucibus dui eget scelerisque. Pellentesque mattis, elit quis auctor laoreet, diam nulla efficitur lectus, auctor interdum nibh ante eu mauris. Aliquam lobortis felis felis, nec cursus turpis pulvinar eget. Donec et dignissim metus, ac consectetur massa. Ut posuere turpis sit amet mollis porta. Pellentesque et metus feugiat, rhoncus tortor non, ullamcorper urna. Duis faucibus leo at pulvinar interdum. Nunc auctor imperdiet metus. Maecenas et aliquet ante, at dictum justo. Donec tellus metus, pharetra eget orci id, porta imperdiet dui. Curabitur a porta quam.

Proin nunc est, interdum non metus nec, porttitor rutrum enim. Quisque accumsan rutrum ligula, ultrices ultrices lorem tempus volutpat. In consequat ipsum at massa malesuada faucibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi id convallis mi, a eleifend nibh. Cras placerat eros ipsum, ultricies luctus mauris vehicula sit amet. Mauris tristique nisl eget molestie tincidunt.

Ut enim quam, pharetra nec risus id, lacinia imperdiet augue. Vivamus ultrices enim sit amet sem dignissim, eu cursus turpis varius. Praesent tempor vehicula pretium. Cras congue faucibus sapien eu aliquet. Sed sit amet purus lacinia, condimentum felis vel, tincidunt ligula. Aenean interdum, metus ut suscipit facilisis, libero tellus consequat orci, ut consectetur augue mauris sed quam. Fusce luctus metus orci, dignissim auctor est porta eget. Aliquam cursus magna pharetra, euismod felis a, consequat lacus. Integer pellentesque ante vitae interdum molestie. Maecenas commodo eros ut dui sagittis, vitae elementum nisi congue. Vestibulum nec malesuada tortor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur sit amet ante vitae nunc feugiat dapibus. Nunc metus urna, pretium eu mauris nec, bibendum convallis lorem.

Nam sed posuere dui. Morbi lobortis auctor posuere. Sed hendrerit leo at urna consequat, sed porta velit mattis. Vivamus in tristique ante. Integer nisi leo, consequat vitae metus vel, pretium pretium dui. Donec egestas cursus justo, ut auctor mi viverra vitae. Nulla at iaculis augue. Aenean dignissim ante sed tellus sagittis viverra.

Phasellus vulputate et ante efficitur lacinia. Morbi a aliquet tellus, id lacinia ipsum. Suspendisse magna ante, dignissim nec mauris eu, tempus bibendum ligula. Morbi ultricies elit vitae metus mattis pulvinar. Morbi sit amet ex convallis, luctus nisl at, tristique nisl. Morbi nec fringilla nulla. Proin in ante vel nulla congue rutrum eget at ipsum. Proin quis libero orci.
</div>

<img class="background" src="https://www.arborday.org/images/hero/medium/hero-green-leaves-in-sunlight.jpg"></img>

<img class="footer" src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-brandeis-blue-solid-color-background.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted?